# How to fix error "Unexpected failure during lint analysis. StackOverflowError"

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew, android-lint

After updating lint to version 7.0.2. I get an error in task
`app:lintDebug`
`Error: Unexpected failure during lint analysis of SomeClass.kt (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)`
and in stack trace I can see the error

```
Stack: StackOverflowError:KotlinUMethod$Companion.access$getKotlinMemberOrigin(KotlinUMethod.kt:129)?KotlinUMethod.<init>(KotlinUMethod.kt:38)?KotlinUMethod$Companion.create(KotlinUMethod.kt:147)?KotlinConverter$convertDeclaration$5$1.invoke(KotlinUastLanguagePlugin.kt:538)?KotlinConverter$convertDeclaration$5$1.invoke(KotlinUastLanguagePlugin.kt:200)?KotlinConverter$convertDeclaration$1$1.invoke(KotlinUastLanguagePlugin.kt:517)?KotlinConverter$convertDeclaration$1$1.invoke(KotlinUastLanguagePlugin.kt:200)?KotlinConverter.convertDeclaration$kotlin_uast_uast_kotlin(KotlinUastLanguagePlugin.kt:861)
```

Somebody know the solution for this problem?

Comment: That means either the process doesn't have enough RAM, or you have infinite recursion in one of your lint rules.  Haveyou added any custom linters lately?

Comment: I have custom lint rules, but they worked without problems before the gradle update

Comment: I would disable them all and reenable them 1 at a time to determine which is actually breaking things.  Then post the rule and you'll get better help.

Comment: I disabled all custom lint rules and found that the error was still there